# .htaccess Redirect based on SSL Protocol

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, https

Following the [POODLE SSL 3.0 exploit](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.ie/2014/10/this-poodle-bites-exploiting-ssl-30.html) we are removing support for SSL 3.0 accross our servers. Ideally we would like to clearly let users on legacy clients know why they aren't able to access the site now.

We could redirect IE6 users to a help page automatically, but as a neater, cross client solution, is it possible to create a .htaccess directive to redirect clients based on them trying to negotiate a connection using the SSL 3.0 protocol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SSL:SSL_PROTOCOL} ^SSLv3$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://zmap.io/sslv3/ [L,R=302]
```

This redirects it to https://zmap.io/sslv3/ but you can change the URL to your own help page.